# To randomly and evenly distribute forms among a group of persons

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in these technologies and I got stuck in a problem which is like.

EXAMPLE : We have a group of 150 people and I want to take assessment of each and every one of them by the people themselves, for that we  need to send a form of 1 person to 5 random persons among the 150.(this goes with all the 150 persons.)

And I got stuck in my test code as it randomly send the forms more than 5 times. Can anyone help me OUT!!!

THE sample code I have tried which didn't worked is ::

```
   for ($i= 0; $i <=count($data); $i++) 
       {
          $j=$i;
          $random = array();
          for ($k = $j; $k <= $j+2; $k++) 
            {
            $random[$i." form of"][$k." sent to"] = 
              rand(1,count($data));
            if (in_array($k, $random[$i]))
            {
                echo $k." is already in array at ".$random[$i][$k];
            }
       }
       print_r($random);
       echo "round"."$i<br>";
      }
```